# Firebase order by existence of a child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a very large database of users that I need to paginate through. The structure is as follows

```
users > -userId > logs > -logId > {type, timestamp, ...}
```

Not all users have logs so according to the data order docs if I orderBy "logs" these users should appear first (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order)

> When using orderByChild(), data that contains the specified child key
>   is ordered as follows:
>
> Children with a null value for the specified child key come first.

As a result I am trying to use the following code to retrieve the last 5 users with logs but am running out of memory on the cloud platform (2GB). Should I be adding an index to assist with this query or is my syntax here incorrect?

```
admin.database().ref("users").orderByChild("logs").limitToLast(5).once("value", (snapshot) => {
```

Is there a better way to fetch a limited group of users who have logs? Any feedback would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I be adding an index to assist with this query or is my syntax here incorrect?

The answer to that is *always* yes. Without an index in your security rules, the server will send all data at the location to the client, which then orders and filters it.

So for your query, your rules will need to contain an index on `logs` under the `users` node.

Comment: That makes sense. Add the following rule fixed performance and data usage as you suggested     "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["logs"]
    }. Thank you!